# delete not working with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-delete

The following code is not working even though I've tested it by putting this on the page alone. To make this clear just after this query I'm doing a select query to display all the user in the DB.

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM Projet_Client WHERE username = '$_GET[d]'");
echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-middle'><strong>Succès</strong>, le 
client a été supprimé.</div>";
```

Here is the "echo" of the query to show you how it looks like :

```
DELETE FROM Projet_Client 
WHERE 
username = 'a75ea99ce47306ec259d4c905bb9c3f762a531ee'
```

(I'm using my sql). Thank you.

I changed the code ant it looks like this :

```
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM Projet_Client WHERE username= :username');
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_GET['d']); 
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'Exception -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

However no exception are being throw.

**The problem has been solved. I had to change the constraint with the foreign key : ON DELETE = CASCADE**

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `$_GET[d]` is not valid? it should be `$_GET['d']` or `$_GET["d"]`. As Dominik already mentioned you should use prepared statements to do this.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch As `$_GET` is in quotes no need to add quotes in index

Comment: @B.Desai - thank you for explanation. I tried this it is really working. I never used this that way :D - Learning everyday...

Comment: May be a typo in the original - but is 'Projet_Client' correct?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, or should I say 'Oui', if you speak French.

Comment: If you try to use a prepare `$stmt = $db->prepare('/your query/ where username = :username')`, `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_GET['d'])`, `$stmt->execute();`, is the delete working or not? Or do you have a db connection problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did use prepared statement before that and I checked for typos in request. I even added "`" to the query to see if this would change something. The only time this query worked is when it was alone in the page. So my conclusion is that there is something that I can't do if DELETE query is done.

Comment: Well, he cant go into the DELETE condition, because $GET[d] isnt defined -> he skips. if(iset($GET['d'])) should do it here.

Comment: @Celebrombore it does validate that condition because the div inside is showing properly

Comment: Oh ok :D Is your a href right then? So does it show the correct values?

Comment: @Celebrombore i think yes because the sql query in my post is done via the echo function  after i clicked the href :(

Comment: Does the mysql user account used in the PDO connection have delete privilege on the specified table? Since you use [`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) an `Exception` will not be thrown. I suggest setting it to throw an exception replacing `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` so you can see the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the query is being executed properly ? 
Your query looks okay to me.

Maybe you can try to echo the error (if there is one) by using this :

```
if ($conn->query($sql) !== false) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
```

}

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to see if this returns something

Comment: [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues) returns a `PDOStatement` upon success, not `true` You would need to use `$conn->query($sql) !== false`.